# Title: Problem connecting to LDAP server with Xamarin.Forms project c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ldap, connection

I have a problem with connecting to our LDAP server, using the NuGet package “Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard2_0”.
My application is a Xamarin.Forms, with the Andoid & UWP part, based on NetStandard 2.0, using Visual Studio 2019, updated.
I could not find any built-in functionality in Netcore2.0 for using LDAP,
That is why I used the Nuget Package (Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard2_0 by Novell, dsbenghe, mkostreba).

I have also used an LDAP query tool for Windows to test the connection, and that works.
But when I try to establish a connection in my app, I get an error with error code 91.
I have tried it with the full hostname, and with the direct ip address of the domain server, but I get the same error result. I have tried this with debugging UWP, not android.
I haven't started on making a correct credentials query yet, because the connection itself should first be ok.

This is my code: (under a simple button clicked)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace App1.view
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
                conn.Connect("ldapserverhostname", 389);
                conn.Bind("username query", "some password");
                DisplayAlert("Error", "succesvol", "ok");
                conn.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (LdapException f)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", f.ResultCode.ToString(), "ok");
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", f.Message, "ok");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Who could help me with this?

update 16 apr 2020:
I have established a connection + successful bind with our LDAP server using WPF NetCore console application, and also with a WPF NetCore desktop application, using the same serverinfo and user query info.
But I cannot get this working under Xamarin.Forms UWP or with a dedicated UWP app. Firewall of the computer is out of the question (I believe), because I am able to communicate with the LDAP server in multiple ways.
I have tried it with sideloading my Xamarin.Forms UWP app, but no result. >> Jumps to the first catch, every time.

Besides using the Novell Ldap Nuget, I have also tried the Windows Compatibility Pack for NetCore app in my UWP and Xamarin.Forms UWP app, but that will result in an "not supported platform" error.

here is my working code from the WPF NetCore desktop app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
using Novell.Directory;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string ldapHost = "fullyhostname.com";
        String loginDN = "CN=MyUserName,OU=HK,something=Users,DC=ourdomainname,DC=com";
        String password = "mypassword";
        LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
        try
        {
            conn.Connect(ldapHost, 389);
            if (conn.Connected)
            {
                MessageBoxResult r = MessageBox.Show("connection succeeded");
            }
            conn.Bind(loginDN, password);
            MessageBoxResult t = MessageBox.Show("bind succeeded");
        }
        catch (LdapException f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error1:" + "code= " + f.ResultCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Error1:" + "code= " + f.LdapErrorMessage);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + f.Message);
            return;
        }
        conn.Disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you ruled out basic connectivity issues between your device and your server?  Is that port open in your firewall?

Comment: hi. yes. i have only run the code in debug, and on the same machine domain firewall if off, and on the same machine i am able to connect with a ldap query tool.

Comment: you need to test your DEVICE (or emulator).  Emulators are VM's with their own networking stack and may not behave the same as code running on your desktop.

Comment: so if i build and compile my project, it could behave in another way then in VS VM (for UWP) for example, it suddenly could work?
i do have internet connection in my application when i debug, that is confirmed

Comment: this is a networking issue, and networking issues are dependent on the platform providing the underlying connection.  An Android VM and an Android device and a Windows desktop are three completely different environments from a networking standpoint.

Comment: I have updated the info in my question >> that i have tried to connect during UWP debugging. I will test the connection outside of Visual Studio >> install the app and test it

Comment: @Jason I have updated the info in the question, with what i tried and what worked and what not worked.